# While in VS Code editor Zen mode, is it possible to configure the layout to replace the terminal window with GitHub Copilot Chat extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

i'm curious if it's possible to configure VScode editor to replace the terminal window with an installed extension, specifically GitHub's Copilot chat? [image: terminal window screencap]

Answer (score 0):

this solution is just as good as what i wanted - the editor monitor is in portrait layout, so I have more 'Y' real estate - to get the chat window in the bottom I spilt the editor horizontally and selected `open session in editor`

this lets me have bottom ~1/3 of monitor as copilot chat aka SilentJarvis

---

[image: a just as good solution screenshot]

---